# MSAccess.EXE remains open in the background after quitting: VBA/Form object issue

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a really weird issue with a VBA function running in Access. When this function is called, something happens to Access that keeps it from truly quitting in the Task Manager. If this function does not run, Access will quit normally. I feel like it has something to do with passing a form object as a parameter, but I can't understand why this is happening.

The Call to the function looks like this:

```
...
With Forms!frmbuytool
    '...setting visible properties of form objects
    SetColumnOrder (!sfmReordersView.Form)
End with
...
```

The function looks like this:

```
Public Sub SetColumnOrder(frm As Form)
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim Username As String
Dim DataSheetID As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
Username = Environ("USERNAME")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DatasheetID FROM sysDataSheets WHERE DataSheetName = """ & frm.Name & """")
DataSheetID = rs!DataSheetID
'load up user settings
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM sysUserSettings WHERE Username = """ & Username & """ AND DatasheetID = " & DataSheetID)
'if no settings are found for the user, use the defaults
If rs.EOF Then
    If IsRowUser Then
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM sysUserSettings WHERE Username = ""ROW_Default"" AND DatasheetID = " & DataSheetID)
    Else
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM sysUserSettings WHERE Username = ""CAN_Default"" AND DatasheetID = " & DataSheetID)
    End If
End If
'Apply settings
Do While Not rs.EOF
    With frm.Controls(rs!ColumnName)
        .ColumnOrder = rs!ColumnOrder
        .ColumnWidth = rs!ColumnWidth
        .ColumnHidden = rs!ColumnHidden
    End With
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
frm.Refresh

Set frm = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

I added the "Set frm = Nothing" thinking that somehow the form object is not being released, but it didn't help.

Thanks for any insights you can provide!

Comment: `SetColumnOrder (!sfmReordersView.Form)` - this call is wrong. You are evaluating the form instead of just passing it as reference. Try `Call SetColumnOrder(!sfmReordersView.Form)` or `SetColumnOrder !sfmReordersView.Form`

Comment: @Andre - OMG you are completely right. Thank you for pointing that out. This solved the problem I was having!

Comment: FWIW this is documented [here on docs.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201612122152274158757)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call with extra parentheses

```
SetColumnOrder (!sfmReordersView.Form)
```

was the problem. You are evaluating the form object instead of just passing it as reference. Use

```
Call SetColumnOrder(!sfmReordersView.Form)
```

or

```
SetColumnOrder !sfmReordersView.Form
```